# CheckedListBox Horizontal Scroll bar is not allowing me to see all text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, horizontal-scrolling, checkedlistbox

I have a custom control based on CheckedListBox

```
public CustomCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    public void AddItems(CustomCollection MyCollection)
    {
        foreach(var C in MyCollection.Items)
        {
             // Some logic is here to determine if an item should be added.
             this.Items.Add(C);    // The C object has a string overload
        }
    }
}
```

When this control is used with some long text the horizontal scroll bar doesn't seem to be sized correctly. When i scroll to the right the text is cut off.

If i clear the Items collection and write its contents again after the control is already loaded then the horizontal scroll bar is sized correctly.

Any idea what could be causing this?

I have the same issue if just using the standard CheckedListBox.

On the red line there about about 5 characters missing at the end. It happens with all character types.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the `ListBox` implementation, using different methods for item text width measurement, which is causing the behavior you are experiencing.

To fix that, you can use the following helper (warning: uses `ListBox` private implementation members)

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    public static class ListBoxUtils
    {
        public static void UpdateHorizontalScrollbar(this ListBox target)
        {
            updateHorizontalScrollbarFunc(target);
        }
        private static readonly Action<ListBox> updateHorizontalScrollbarFunc = CreateUpdateScrollbarFunc();
        private static Action<ListBox> CreateUpdateScrollbarFunc()
        {
            var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ListBox), "target");
            var body = Expression.Block(
                Expression.Assign(Expression.Field(target, "maxWidth"), Expression.Constant(-1)),
                Expression.Call(target, "UpdateHorizontalExtent", null)
            );
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<ListBox>>(body, target);
            return lambda.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

After modifying items collection, just call

```
listBox.UpdateHorizontalScrollbar();
```

Comment: Very interesting bit of code. I like it but it doesn't work. Im calling it directly after i call the method to populate the checkedlistbox. This is populated before it is displayed.

Comment: @CathalMF I've tested it in both constructor, `Load` event and after the form is displayed and it is working. Make sure `CheckedListBox.UseCompatibleTextRendering` property is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fought with this for some time now.  I found a solution (I can't find it again to give credit) where I change the `HorizontalExtent` based on the strings length combined with `CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(g, CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal).Width`

The full method look like this but there are some improvements to the check state that can be made.

```
public void SetHorizontalExtent()
    {
        // Create a Graphics object to use when determining the size of the largest item in the ListBox.
        Graphics g = cbl_causeCodes.CreateGraphics();

        int maxSize = 0;
        foreach (var item in cbl_causeCodes.Items)
        {
            //CheckBoxState state = causeCodes.Contains(config.Value) ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
            int hzSize = (int)(g.MeasureString(item.ToString(), cbl_causeCodes.Font).Width);

            hzSize += CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(g, CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal).Width;
            if (hzSize > maxSize)
                maxSize = hzSize;
        }

        cbl_causeCodes.HorizontalExtent = maxSize;
    }
```